# Testing for proper behaviour on memory allocation failures

Tags: c++, c, linux, testing, dynamic-memory-allocation

We have a relatively large code base for a Linux server, it's dynamically linked-in libraries and server modules loaded during startup using `dlopen()`. The server as well as most of the other components are written in C++11, but some are in C99.

What approaches could one use to test whether the server, its dependencies and modules properly handle memory allocation failures, e.g.`malloc`/`calloc` returning `NULL`, operators `new` and `new[]` throwing `std::bad_alloc` etc, including allocation failures from `std::string::resize()` and such?

In the past, I've tried using [memory allocation hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) to inject memory allocation failures into C applications, but I think these don't work for C++. What other options or approaches should I be looking at?

Comment: Use `ulimit` to limit your maximum data segment size, to trivially force random allocation failures.

Comment: I'm always testing with valgrind. Run-times are a problem, but it's worth it.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. The question is already too broad and too opinionated for one of them.

Comment: @Olaf It's a real case. I edited my question to better reflect the situation. If you still think it is too broad, would you kindly suggest how to best split the question?

Comment: Are you using gcc? Said differently would the gcc-only memory allocation hooks be available for the C part?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, hooking into C malloc is enough, since under the hood the gcc C++ default implementation of operator new does call malloc and you confirmed you only needed a gcc compatible solution.

I could demonstrate it with that simple program:

mem.c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
    int ival;
    std::string str;

public:
    A(int i, std::string s): ival(i), str(s) {}
    A(): ival(0), str("") {};

    int getIval() const {
        return ival;
    }
    std::string getStr() const {
        return str;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a(2, "foo");

    std::cout << &a << " : " << a.getIval() << " - " << a.getStr() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

memhook.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void *__libc_malloc(size_t size);

void* malloc (size_t size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocating %u\n", size);
    return NULL;
//    return __libc_malloc(size);
}
```

When returning NULL (as above), the program displays:

```
Allocating 16
Allocating 100
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Abandon (core dumped)
```

That proves that returning NULL from the declared malloc function results in a `std::bad_alloc` exception in C++ code

When uncommenting the `return __libc_malloc(size);` the allocations are done by the libc malloc and the output becomes:

```
Allocating 16
0xbfe8d2e8 : 2 - foo
```

Answer (score -1):

On linux you can hook into the operating system to force allocation to fail

man 2 mlockall

`mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE);`

Should do what you want.

Comment: Are you sure `mlockall` does that? IMHO it only prevents memory from being paged to the swap area.

Comment: man 2 mlockall is likely to be definitive if you don't want to try it...       "mlockall() locks all pages mapped into the address space of the calling
       process.   This includes the pages of the code, data and stack segment,
       as well as shared libraries, user space kernel data, shared memory, and
       memory-mapped files.  All mapped pages are guaranteed to be resident in
       RAM when the call returns successfully; the  pages  are  guaranteed  to
       stay in RAM until later unlocked.
"

Comment: I still fail to understand how `mlockall` could help with respect to the question.